# Working with configurable value

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, configuration, app-config

**Background:** I am working with an application suite which constitutes both connected *(client-server)* and disconnected *(message based services)* sub systems. Each of the sub system in the suite has its own configuration file. As of now, these configurations are maintained individually within the application directory.

**Concern:** Maintenance of these configuration files are getting out of hand due to our requirement of it being dynamic *(It is part of requirement that we should be able to switch/update configuration entries on specific time of day/week/month to adjust the system behaviors)*

**Question:** Is there any better approach or proven practice to consolidate configurations for better manageability without loosing the required dynamic nature.

**Tried so far:**

Following are the list of solutions we have tried so far *(we are at Srl 4)*. Not sure whether this is the best we could have in order to address our problem.

1. Application specific local configuration as explained. This works
   well but couldn't address any of the concern listed.
2. Configurations are stored in database and loaded into application as
   in-memory objects. This solve the issue of consolidation. But needed to restart the individual system to get up-to-date configuration values in case of change.
3. We can't afford to restart service ( Issue listed under Srl 2) and hence implemented a polling with a policy which refresh the in-memory objects every 2 minutes. This is was fine but irrespective of whether there any change or     not, the polling procedure continue to refresh the cache at every 2 minutes.
4. In order to avoid unnecessary polling (Issue listed under Srl 3), we have implemented a configuration versioning. This help us to avoid refreshing data if there is no change in the configuration.

Comment: The database approach probably has merit, have you explored the option of using SQL Server Service Broker, in conjunction with the External Activator?  You could use an after update trigger to send a message that would effectively trigger some application code external to the database.  It's a lot of moving parts, but I think it could be made pretty robust.  This post may help: https://sqluninterrupted.com/2012/09/14/sending-sql-notification-to-c-application-using-service-broker/

Comment: @mars-red, Thanks for the comment. In our case, we have different database system to interact with including sql server, MySql and mogoDb and the eventual idea is to replace sql server. So your proposal looks promising. But I can't go in that route due to the direction we are heading.

Comment: I understand.  What about a bespoke configuration service hooked up to the various subsystems via MSMQ?  The service could be responsible for "watching" a central configuration repository (file system, or lightweight db, or whatever). That sounds like the only thing that's likely to get you anything better than what you've already tried.  Of course it would require that MSMQ is available in all environments (where the configuration service lives, and where the various sub-systems live).  Accessing remote queues does require attention to security issues, of course.

Comment: @mars-red, Your solution sound reasonable. The only concern I have is latency when consuming service/application that require a configured value. This might very negligible time  but not sure. In our simple term, configured values should be part of the system that consumes it (internal dependency) and not dependency (external dependency).  With this solution in place, all of our service has one more dependency to worry and manage. Secondly, the amount of work involved is likely more than our current solution. So I am doubtful whether this world become a solution for us.

Comment: sorry I couldn't be of more help.